# эффект при наведении на текст svg

Tags: jquery, css, css3, svg

на сайте https://vintage.com.ua заголовок там есть слово business серым написано при наведении на него слов как бы рябить как можно реализовать такой эффект [image]

Answer (score 1):

Смысл этого эффекта в том, чтобы с помощью `clip mask` разбить текст на некие слои и потом поверх текста делать смещение этих слоёв .

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.glitch {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes noise-anim {
  0% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 43px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(28px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(84px, 9999px, 87px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(36px, 9999px, 56px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(91px, 9999px, 86px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 80px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 76px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 71px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(48px, 9999px, 85px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(77px, 9999px, 40px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(83px, 9999px, 58px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(100px, 9999px, 28px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(29px, 9999px, 82px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 3px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 24px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 95px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(44px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(21px, 9999px, 6px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(73px, 9999px, 71px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(35px, 9999px, 55px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
  }
}
.glitch:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 25px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(19px, 9999px, 87px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(64px, 9999px, 40px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 100px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(70px, 9999px, 32px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(52px, 9999px, 81px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(23px, 9999px, 39px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(1px, 9999px, 14px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(36px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(12px, 9999px, 69px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(18px, 9999px, 3px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(86px, 9999px, 49px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(32px, 9999px, 25px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(65px, 9999px, 4px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 18px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(56px, 9999px, 16px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(89px, 9999px, 35px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(51px, 9999px, 45px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 100px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(72px, 9999px, 26px, 0);
  }
}
.glitch:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 blue;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="glitch" data-text="GLITCH">GLITCH</div>
```